# question regarding <img> and thumbnails

Tags: thumbnails

I have a photo site which renders previews of my photos in a  tag when i hover some dots. (see http://johanberntsson.se/photo/).

But it feels kinda stupid to load the full image in to an img-tag. Because as far as i know, theres no difference between loading the image with its original size versus adding height and width attributes to it.

Got any suggestions how to improove my preview function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as client side is concerned, there's nothing you can do. If you're worried about how long it takes the image to load, you could always pre-load them with javascript. The only other thing would be to create a few sizes of your image on the server.

Comment: The images are about 1mb each. Just thought that my hosting provider might whine when a lot of data is sent/recieved when a lot of people are previewing images. But maybe it isnt such a big deal?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it matters. If you're worried about your hosting provider whining, the way you're doing it now works fine.  It would be good to make two sizes on the server: full size and thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

You should resize the image to get better speed. Here's an example in php

```
//Blob if image in database
$blob = mysql_fetch_...();
//else blob point to filename
$blob = "filename.jpg";

   $gd = imagecreatefromstring($blob);
   $resized = imagecreatetruecolor(X, Y); // new image dimensions
   imagecopyresampled(....);


   imagejpeg($resized);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading all the thumbnails in a giant sprite image used as a background image. Then position the background a the right place to have the right image a the right place.

This will improve the loading speed by loading only 1 image and allow the browser to cache the request of the image so, next time the user come to your site, it will load pretty fast.

Comment: sounds good except it's a little impractical as Berntsson is using the site for his personal photos and it'd be a pain to load pictures into a big sprite every time.

Comment: Your right, so the best to do is to resize all the images to the real get something more efficient or to pre-load them as you mention. This is the quickest way in a "purely" html way.